# `^M` at the end of each line of text files generated under Windows

Tags: character-encoding

I was wondering why if you open a textfile made in Windows notepad under unix you will find that it has `^M` where there should be a new line?

My understanding is that in Windows, every line is ended with `\r\n`, ie  `0x0D0A` in ASCII, while `^M` has ASCII value `0x5E4D`. I cannot relate these two from one to the other.

Comment: In Windows you can use a better editor like Notepad++.  It will allow you to save the files with UNIX line endings but view it in Windows as if it had Windows line endings.  Then you can view it in both OS fine.

Comment: See also [Jeff Atwood's take on it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're right about the line endings being important; both OSes expect the line to end with "\n", but Windows also adds a "\r" before that that unix doesn't expect, so unix programs will output the "\r" in their own way.

The file doesn't actually end with the two characters "^" and "M", that's just a common way to represent unprintable characters. Programs will output "^" and a letter corresponding to the byte's value, starting with A for 1. M is the 13th letter, and '\r' is ASCII code 13 (or 0xD, as you said), so you see "^M"

Comment: That's also short-hand for Ctrl-M, which is how you get that character with the keyboard.

Comment: You can use the command line utilities `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` to convert text files between formats.

Comment: @Chris True, but doesn't really have anything to do with the question

Comment: Thanks!  (1) I was wondering what programs will output unprintable characters that way? For example, are all text editors/viewers work that way? (2) what kinds of unprintable characters are treated that way, and what kinds are not? For example, why don't text viewers output `^J` for `\n`?

Comment: (3) I also remember sometimes some unprintable characters are printed as a square with its oct number inside. So I wonder when an unprintable character is output this way and when as Ctrl + some character?

Comment: The ^M representation predates GUI text editors by years, if not decades.

Comment: @Tim, there are several conventions. Some print `?` for nonprintable characters (or `?` on inverse, or some such), sometimes `^X` for ctrl-X, or `\xx` for the character with hexadecimal code xx. And @ChrisNava is right that this predates GUIs by decades.